# Problems opening solution file in Visual Studio 2005 running under Parallels

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2005, parallels

I wrote a simple program in C# on Visual Studio 2005 on a windows machine at work. I tried to open the solution file at home in Visual Studio 2005, inside of Parallels, on my mac and I get the error:

`Unable to read the project file 'filename.csproj'. Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.`

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well I figured it out. The shared folders are .psf which is invalid to Visual Studio.

In case  anyone is interested:

1. Inside of XP in Parallels, Map a Network Drive 'X' to the 'Home' folder.
2. Open the Solution file in the Networked Drive using Visual Studio
3. Done.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are the project file is referencing a hostname that is only valid within your network at work.  You'll have to find the hostname it is referencing and manually change it to one that works within your network at home.